# Why was this question on closed by 1 mod as "requesting personal medical advice", even though the same mod said it was on-topic last year?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

The [question](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1190/43)  is:

> Title: Vaseline is used to reduce scarring following keratosis. Is there a substitute ointment that will be less uncomfortable when used near the eye?
>
> Body: After scaling a seborrheic keratosis one typically uses [Vaseline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaseline) to help reduce scarring.  It is uncomfortable when it goes into the eye. which may happen when the scaling was near (< 3 mm) the eye. Is there a substitute ointment that will be less uncomfortable when used near the eye?

I don't understand the closure by 1 mod because:

1. This is a general question for improving the treatment of patients going through scaling a seborrheic keratosis located near their eye. It is not a personal medical advice but instead is a generic question on a typical treatment that is useful to the millions of patients going through it every year.
2. Furthermore, [a moderator and a user previously agreed](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1191/43)  that the phrasing was on-topic:

   > Had it instead asked something like: Vaseline is used to reduce scarring following keratosis. Is there a substitute ointment that will be less uncomfortable when used near the eye?, I think it would have been considered acceptable.

   I had edited the question to use this approved phrasing.

So why was the question closed by 1 mod as "requesting personal medical advice" by the same mod who previously agreed with the current phrasing?

Answer (score 3):

The key part of your quote from the Moderator is

> **I think** it would have been considered acceptable.

Maybe after further thought it is not acceptable, and I agree.

Asking for a substitute ointment that will be less uncomfortable is a personal advice question as

1. It is asking for another ointment medically equivalent and suitable for you, and
2. It may be less uncomfortable for one person but not the other.

It is personal medical advice so it is off-topic.